# Как выполнить ajax запрос при появлений блока в html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

К примеру есть элемент c классом `block с display: none`, если вдруг станет `display: block` выполнить `ajax` запрос, такое возможно?

Comment: Конечно так можно попробовать сделать, но в 99% случаях лучше отталкиваться от того, почему он стал вдруг `display: block`. А не постфактум реагировать на изменение.

Answer (score 2):

```js
setTimeout(() => element.style.display = "block", 1000);

let elementObserver = new MutationObserver((e) => console.log(e[0].target.style.display));

elementObserver.observe(element, {attributeFilter: ["style"]});
```

```css
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  
  background-color: #121;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```